# Recent Comments in the Activity Feed plugin?

Tags: plugins, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-comments

Does the Activity Feed plugin include comments on stories with the same root URL?

If so, can the Activity Feed plugin be limited to or exclude comments?

If not, is there a "recent comments" plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, comments do not show up in the activity feed. There is a bug report on this: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=14698 . Looks like we just have to wait to get this fixed.